# Interval in Angular Service Forces DOM Update

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following Angular service defined in my project...

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class NodeService extends WebService {

  private intervalId: number | undefined;

  public start(frequency: number = 1000): void {
    if (this.intervalId === undefined) {
      this.intervalId = window.setInterval(() => { ... }, frequency);
    }
  }
}
```

When `start` is executed, it forces a DOM update every *(frequency)* milliseconds, even though the body of the `setInterval` function is empty.

Any ideas why?

Comment: maybe because angular captures it as a browser event so change detection runs. If you don't want, it, please set the component to use change detection ONPUSH

Comment: Is it updating the DOM or is it only running change detection? When change detection runs, it should only update the DOM if something actually changed. [This page](https://angular.io/guide/zone#when-apps-update-html) from the docs lists the reasons change detection would be run automatically.  Performing an async operation such as setTimeout is one of the reasons.